# How does Dexter handle the logistics of his murders?

Tags: dexter

When Dexter murders someone he always prepares the room with:

- lots of plastic foil
- pictures of victims
- small details for atmosphere
- etc

But we only see him dispose the bodies.

The amount of plastic foil and the blood that must have been spilled must be very hard to dispose of. Just the foil alone would need one round trip with his small car.

And then he mostly only has one night to prepare, play and dispose. How does he handle this?

Is there any mention in the series or some canon explanation on  this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of the famous quotes of Season 6:

> "Most of the people here don't have two rolls of duct tape, 80 yards of plastic sheeting and a surgical saw in their trunk." - Dexter.

Dexter's car trunk can accommodate the plastic foil and/or other items that are used in the murder scene. What we see is Dexter dropping two/three plastic bags into the sea but there has to be more such bags containing the body parts along with the plastic/other items used in the murder scene.

Comment: all the plastic can't possibly fit in two / three of those little bags. It must be ca 50-60m² of plastic foil.

Comment: I assume that he gets the plastic foil to the murder place in his vehicle in one trip (he has a SUV I believe), so he could as well dispose it in one trip right? what we are shown are 2-3 bags that he throws in to the sea, but there could be more. I think we can only guess here.

Comment: that's why I asked the question :) I am not looking for guesswork but for an in-world explanation or something similar.

Comment: This is one of the famous quotes from S06 : "Most of the people here don't have two rolls of duct tape, 80 yards of plastic sheeting and a surgical saw in their trunk." - Dexter. Trunk here means Dexter's car trunk.

Comment: There is a scene (before he flips his SUV and rolls and has amnesia and must trace back where he hid the body (in teh punch bag)) you see there is an extra compartment under his boot (in the SUV) - he lifts a flap to reveal some filled bags.